# C function and arrays without value change

Tags: c

I want to pass a array to function and I want to change it within the function without changing the original array using c. Can I do it?

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display(int age[]) {
    age[0]=3;
    age[1]=4;
}
int main() {
    int ageArray[] = { 2,3 };
    display(ageArray);//Passing array element ageArray[2] only.
    printf("%d", ageArray[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make a copy, and pass the copy.  Or have the called function make a copy.  I suppose if the dimensions are fixed, you could embed it in a struct and pass the struct by value.

Comment: You need to duplicate the array.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

void display(int age[])
{
   age[0]=3;
    age[1]=4;
}

int main()
{
    int ageArray[] = { 2,3 };
    display(ageArray); //Passing array element ageArray[2] only.
    printf("%d",ageArray[0]);
    return 0;
} my code is like this how can i make a copy of this array

Comment: Create a copy of the array passed within your function. All changes made to this copy of the array will be local to the function.

Comment: Please don't change or extend your question with a comment. Use the "EDIT" function of the question and mark the edition that you can see what has been changed.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C doesn't have to concept of passing arrays to a function. There is always a pointer passed to the function independent of the function signature:

```
void function(int *Array);
void function(int Array[]);
```

You must make a copy of the array if you want to avoid modification of the original array. For that purpose you must pass the size of the Array:

```
void function(int *Array, size_t Size);
```

Now you can create the copy.

Comment: Thank you very much